# Create a file relative path for secure server certificate

Tags: dart

I'm working on a Dart HttpServer using SSL, which looks something like this:

```dart
class Server {
  //The path for the database is relative to the code's entry point (main.dart)
  static const String CERTIFICATE_DB_PATH = '../lib/server/';
  static const String CERTIFICATE_DB_PASS = '*******';
  static const String CERTIFICATE_NAME = 'CN=mycert';

  Future start() async {
    SecureSocket.initialize(database: CERTIFICATE_DB_PATH, password: CERTIFICATE_DB_PASS);
    httpServer = await HttpServer.bindSecure(ADDRESS, PORT, certificateName: CERTIFICATE_NAME);
    listenSubscription = httpServer.listen(onRequest, onError: onError);
  }

  //more server code here
}
```

This all works exactly as expected, so no problems with the actual certificate or server code. The part that I'm having problems with is mentioned in that first comment. The `CERTIFICATE_DB_PATH` seems to be relative not to the file the `Server` class is defined in, but rather to the file that contains the `main()` method. This means that when I try to write a unit test for this class, the path is no longer pointing to the correct directory. If this were an import, I'd use the `package:packageName/path/to/cert` syntax, but it doesn't seem that applies here. How can I specify the path of the certificate in a way that will work with multiple entry points (actually running the server vs unit tests)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to define the path so it is relative to the source file.
What you can do is to change the current working directory either before you run `main()` or pass a working directory path as argument to `main()`  and let `main()` make this directory the current working directory.

```dart
Directory.current = someDirectory;
```

Comment: I was looking at changing `Directory.current` but that seemed like it might cause a number of other problems for other files in my application. But even if I do that, what would I set it to? Is there anything I could set that would work when the code is run on different systems (multiple developer's machines and production server)? Or would this essentially be the same as using absolute paths?

Comment: I would try to ensure the package root directory to be the current directory first thing in main and align all file access accordingly.